# Multiple aggregation over multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

I want to write a UDF over a data frame that operates as comparing values of particular row against the values from same group, where the grouping is by multiple keys. As UDFs operate on a single row, I want to write a query that returns values from same group in as a new column value.

For example over this
Input:

| id | categoryAB | categoryXY | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | 0.2 | True |
| 2 | A | X | 0.3 | False |
| 3 | A | X | 0.2 | True |
| 4 | B | X | 0.4 | True |
| 5 | B | X | 0.1 | True |
| 6 | B | Y | 0.5 | False |

I can add

- group1: aggregation of value1s from the same <categroyAB, categroyXY> group
- group2: aggregation of value1s from the same <categroyAB, categroyXY> group i.e. same grouping.

Expected result:

| id | categoryAB | categoryXY | value1 | value2 | group1 | group2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | 0.2 | True | [0.2, 0.3, 0.2] | [True, False, True] |
| 2 | A | X | 0.3 | False | [0.2, 0.3, 0.2] | [True, False, True] |
| 3 | A | X | 0.2 | True | [0.2, 0.3, 0.2] | [True, False, True] |
| 4 | B | X | 0.4 | True | [0.4, 0.1] | [True, True] |
| 5 | B | X | 0.1 | True | [0.4, 0.1] | [True, True] |
| 6 | B | Y | 0.5 | False | [0.5] | [False] |

To be more clear about grouping, there are 3 groups in this example

- <A,X> with rows 1, 2 and 3
- <B,X> with rows 4 and 5
- <B,Y> with row 6

I need to implement it in Scala with Spark SQL structures and functions but a generic SQL answer could be guiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more optimized method, but here how I usually do:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  (1, "A", "X", 0.2, true),
  (2, "A", "X", 0.3, false),
  (3, "A", "X", 0.2, true),
  (4, "B", "X", 0.4, true),
  (5, "B", "X", 0.1, true),
  (6, "B", "Y", 0.5, false)
).toDF("id", "categoryAB", "categoryXY", "value1", "value2")

df.join(
  df.groupBy("categoryAB", "categoryXY")
    .agg(
      collect_list('value1) as "group1",
      collect_list('value2) as "group2"
    ),
  Seq("categoryAB", "categoryXY")
).show()
```

The idea is that I compute separately the aggregation on `categoryAB` and `categoryXY`, and then I join the new dataframe to the original one (make sure that `df` is cached if it is the result of heavy computations as otherwise it will be computed twice).

Comment: This didn't directly solved my problem but the proposed idea guided a working solution. The collect_list aggregator is the key. I've also used a struct to merge both groups in one column and then accessed with getAs function in UDF! Thanks @leleogeer!

Comment: You can also post your solution as another answer, it can help other people searching for something similar :)